# What does time complexity really mean in Redis?

Tags: redis

For example, hgetall says time complexity is O(N). If a hash has 5 fields, does that mean Redis is doing 5 operations? I know Redis, based on many benchmarks, can handle upwards of 80-100k operations per second. But what really is an operation? Is it a 1-1 mapping of the time complexity listed for the commands? This would help me map out what my threshold is for queries I'm making to Redis.

Comment: That's not what Big O notation means.

Comment: I know, but how does Big O notation relate to operations in Redis? Claims of 80k operations, but that's for basic hset, or hget commands. Is an hgetall 5 operations if it returns 5 fields?

Comment: Depends on where you got the "claims" from

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks is just one of those sources.

Comment: @dmastylo Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the code:

```
void genericHgetallCommand(client *c, int flags) {
    ... 
    ...
    while (hashTypeNext(hi) != C_ERR) {
            if (flags & OBJ_HASH_KEY) {
                addHashIteratorCursorToReply(c, hi, OBJ_HASH_KEY);
                count++;
            }
            if (flags & OBJ_HASH_VALUE) {
                addHashIteratorCursorToReply(c, hi, OBJ_HASH_VALUE);
                count++;
            }
        }
```

It iterates over all of the keys and values. Therefore the bigger the Hashset the bigger the complexity. Its Line

Comment: I guess my question is what does that mean in terms of "operations per second". I see that thrown all over the place, even on Redis' benchmarking page, but it doesn't accurately explain what an "operation" is.